# Installing other fonts on wine

Tags: wine, fonts

Is there a way to install fonts on wine?

I'm looking to install fonts so i can use them to render text differently on various apps. Specifically myriad.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Wine gets its fonts from four places:

1. The standard system fonts at *`/usr/share/fonts`*.  You can add fonts here by installing font packages from Software Center, if they're available. **Avoid manually copying files here**.
2. Wine's private *`/usr/share/wine/fonts`* folder. You shouldn't add fonts here, but if you see a font in Wine and not in the system - it's probably here. Examples of these fonts include Wine's private marlett, symbol, and tahoma fonts, which are needed for application compatibility but otherwise aren't the best.
3. The *`~/.fonts`* folder in your Home directory. This is where you should manually copy self-installed fonts, either downloaded from the Internet or copied from a Windows install.
4. The equivalent of the C:\Windows\Fonts folder within the current Wine prefix.   Unless you specified the WINEPREFIX environment variable when running Wine, This will generally be located in ~/.wine/drive_c/Windows/fonts.

In the case of conflicts (eg you install the real Tahoma font into your home directory), Wine is smart enough about it and uses the manually-installed ones.

Comment: After you copied fonts it's very important to call the command `sudo fc-cache -fv` otherwise wine will not see these fonts (of will see, but after restarting of your system)

Comment: fc-cache was not enough for me (fonts copied in C:\Windows\Fonts), but after restarting wine programs could use the new fonts

Answer (score 12):

Wine says [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Fonts)

> Font configuration, once a nasty problem, is now much simpler. If you have a collection of TrueType fonts in Windows it's simply a matter of copying the .ttf files into c:\windows\fonts.

Comment: It looks like that link is now dead

Comment: As of 2023, the above link is working and still contains above citation.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is Ubuntu Q&A, but since this answer was so helpful and applied also for both CentOS and Fedora Linux, let me add this:  I've installed a Windows APL interpreter to run under wine, and of course, APL uses (and really needs!) the specialized APL fonts.  Wine 2.0.1 (latest stable ver.) was compiled from source, and on a CentOS 6.6 box, (Linux kernel: 2.6.32-504.el6.i686) using Gnome 2.28.2 Xwindows desktop, I just copied the Apl*.ttf font files into the wine fonts directory ../wine/wine-2.0.1/fonts, the directory which is created when the wine source tarball is unpacked.  Worked fine.  But on an older Fedora kernel (Linux kernel: 2.6.27 25-78.2.56.fc9.i686), also with Gnome ( 2.22.3), when I compiled and built wine, I had to put the APL fonts into the ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts directory, for the APL interpreter to see them.  That is the user directory that is created when wine is first run.  In both cases, wine runs well, and the APL interpreter can see the specialized fonts it needs.

Comment: Minor note:  On the CentOS box, I had not run "make install".  I was running Wine directly from the source hive, using the "wine" wrapper that was included.  Once I ran a proper install of "wine" on the CentOS box, the the behaviour of the two Linux boxes converged - ie. both *require* that the fonts be installed in ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts directory, for the Windows program (the APL interpreter in this case), to actually see the fonts.

Answer (score 3):

If you used PlayOnLinux:

```
~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/YOURPROGRAM/drive_c/windows/Fonts
```

Restart application and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install **PlayOnLinux** which by default after starting it will install several of the Microsoft fonts (Am guessing also found in winetricks).