# ttf-mscorefonts-installer Download Failure

Tags: apt, wine, dpkg, fonts

I know there's already a lot of duplicates for this, but for some reason, I just can't get ttf-mscorefonts-installer to stop bugging me with the error message.

I've followed the steps from here: ["Failure to download extra data files" after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153928/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-after-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installe)

`apt-get` says something about the hash sum not being the same for one of the files. When I manually download the files and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, nothing happens! The command runs without any output!

So, since dpkg-reconfigure doesn't do anything, how do I fix this? I only need Wine for 1 program, and it works just fine. Is there a way to simply turn off the popup?

Comment: Have you tried the answers provided here: http://askubuntu.com/q/543673/58950? Have you tried [purging ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/11/ttf-mscorefonts-installer-ubuntu.html)? Then just manually install the fonts you need [wherever Wine can find them](http://askubuntu.com/a/87295/58950).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@carnendil, thanks for linking that other question. When I installed the 3.6 version of the package, everything worked fine. The download script looks a lot different compared to the 3.4 package, and it didn't have any issues with invalid content headers or hash sum mismatches.