# Photoshop PlayOnLinux unavailable to see installed google fonts

Tags: wine, fonts, playonlinux, google, photoshop

I use Photoshop CC2014 via PlayOnLinux that simulates 32-bit Windows 7.

I need to use google fonts in Photoshop. I install them on Ubuntu, I install them in PlayOnLinux, I install them in Photoshop virtual drive on PlayOnLinux. Fonts still are invisible in Photoshop (however they are visible in Ubuntu generally). How can I install Google Fonts and have them available in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Wine gets its fonts from the following four places:

- The standard system fonts are avilable at `/usr/share/fonts`. You can add fonts here by installing font packages from Software Center or by a ppa, if they're available.
- Wine's private `/usr/share/wine/fonts` folder. You shouldn't add fonts here, but if you see a font in Wine and not in the system - it's probably here.
- The `.fonts` folder in your Home directory. This is where you should manually copy self-installed fonts, either downloaded from the Internet or copied from a Windows install. If this folder is not available create a `.fonts` folder in your `home` and copy the fonts there.
- The equivalent of the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder within the current Wine prefix. Unless you specified the WINEPREFIX environment variable when running Wine, This will generally be located in`~/.wine/drive_c/Windows/fonts`.

So it would be a good bet to copy the fonts either in `.fonts` or 
`~/.wine/drive_c/Windows/fonts`.

Source: [Installing other fonts on wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86335/installing-other-fonts-on-wine)

Answer (score 0):

Copy your fonts to one of these locations or both if you're not sure.

```
~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/<YourApp>/drive_c/windows/Fonts/
~/.PlayOnLinux/fonts/
```

Then restart your system. Just restarting PlayOnLinux does not work somehow.